# Borel-Cantelli lemma proof $\text{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}{ M_n\over{\log n}}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Show $\displaystyle \text{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} {M_n\over{\log n}}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)=1$where $M_n=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}X_k$ and $X_k \text{~ Exp}(\lambda) $

> All I have so far is (which may or may not be useful):
>  $$\text{P}(M_n\leq x)=\text{P}(X_n\leq x)^n=(1- e^{-\lambda x})^n \leq \exp(-n e^{-\lambda x})$$
>  and the condition that 
>  $$|\{n\in \mathbb{N}:X_n\geq b_n\}|<\infty \iff|\{n\in \mathbb{N}: M_n\geq b_n\}|<\infty $$

I need to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma:

$\Sigma_{n\geq 1} \text{P}(A_n)=\infty$ then $\text{P}(A)=1$ where $A=\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n$, to get the answer.

Also, I have already shown that

$$\text{P}(X_n > \frac{1+\epsilon}{\lambda} \log n \text{  i.o.})=1 \text{ for } \epsilon<0$$ and $$\text{P}(X_n > \frac{1+\epsilon}{\lambda} \log n \text{  i.o.})=0 \text{ for }\epsilon>0.$$ So I get the impression that $\frac{X_n(\omega)}{\log n}$ grows like $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Going back to what is in the "spoiler":$|\{n\in \mathbb{N}:\frac{X_n}{\log n} \leq \lambda^{-1}\}|=\infty \Rightarrow |\{\mathbb{N}:\frac{M_n}{\log n} \leq \lambda^{-1}\}|=\infty$ what do I do? Is the correct way to go? Do I try to show $|\{\mathbb{N}:\frac{M_n}{\log n} < \lambda^{-1}\}|<\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ or something?

Comment: I cannot use the spoiler script - but the stuff in the grey may not be required so I decided to separate it.

Comment: it may help to observe that $M_n $ can be written as $T_1 +...+T_n$ where the $T_i \sim exp(i*\lambda)$ and are independent.  E.g., the minimun is $exp(n \lambda)$, then everything starts over and time to next smallest is $exp(n-1) \lambda$

Comment: @mike This is useless to solve this.

Comment: Hint: To show that $$P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} {M_n\over{\log n}}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)=1$$ it suffices to show that, for every positive $\epsilon$, $$P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} {M_n\over{\log n}}\leqslant\frac{1}{\lambda}+\epsilon\right)=1$$ and $$P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} {M_n\over{\log n}}\leqslant\frac{1}{\lambda}-\epsilon\right)=0$$ Indeed, Borel-Cantelli will help to get these...